# product of Maximum of all subarray

Tags: java

I have an Array with some distinct integer data in it and I need to get the max element from all the subarray possible and multiply it.
Here is the example
input :
`{4,7}` 
Required Output:
196

Explanation:
subarray possible

```
{4}=max{4}=4
{7}=max{7}=7
{4,7}=max{4,7}=7
answer=4*7*7=196
```

can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i know, this should do what you want:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arrays = {
            {4},
            {7},
            {4, 7}
        };

        int result = Arrays.stream(arrays).mapToInt((x) -> Arrays.stream(x).max().getAsInt()).reduce(1, Math::multiplyExact);

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

First, the largest value from each of the source arrays is selected.

```
Arrays.stream(arrays).mapToInt(x -> {});
```

To achieve this, we first iterate over each of these arrays in the lambda function of Arrays.stream and get the largest value in the array x by inserting

```
Arrays.stream(x).max().getAsInt()
```

In the last step, the largest numbers from the respective arrays are multiplied together, which is done by the reduce method, which always makes one out of two values until only one is left. The operation used to reduce is `multiplyExact`, the reason for this is that a method `Integer::multiply` unfortunately does not exist (or at least I don't know about it). The special thing about the method `multiplyExact` is that it throws an error as soon as an integer overflow occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Java, but from a algorithmic point of view it could look like this:

```
max_list = empty_list
for i to len(A)
    for j to len(A) - i 
        subset [j, j+i]
        find max of subset
        append max to max_list

result = 1
for i to len(A)
    result = result * A[i]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).